# slf4j decorator is logging the decorator FQCN, not the calling FQCN

Tags: java, slf4j

I've created a decorator class from slf4j `Logger` class since I need to perform a certain check within the `info`, `debug`, etc methods. I'm using the log4j12 binding.

It works fine except for the logged FQCN: it is not the FQCN of the invoking class, but the FQCN of the decorator class.

```
package foo.bar;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class MyLogger implements Logger {

private final Logger logger;
private final boolean traceAndExit;

public MyLogger(Logger logger, boolean traceAndExit) {
    this.logger = logger;
    this.traceAndExit = traceAndExit;
} // MyLogger

@Override
public void info(String message) {
    try {
        logger.info(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (traceAndExit) {
            traceAndExit(e);
        } // if
    } // catch
} // info

...
```

If at any other class `foo.bar.OtherClass` I do this:

```
MyLogger myLogger = new MyLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(OtherClass.class), true);
myLogger.info("this is a message");
```

Then the log I obtain prints `foo.bar.MyLogger` instead of `foo.bar.OtherClass` (`%C` conversion character).

Any idea about how to properly do this? It is mandatory for me to print the FQCN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you did not mention what logging *implementation* you use. slf4j is just a common API shared by various logging implementaions.

Fortunately, at least Logback, Log4j and Log4j 2, which should account for most logging implementatons in the wild, interpret the `%C` format specifier in the same way.

The [Logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) and the [Log4j 2 documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html) define `%C` as "the fully-qualified class name **of the caller** issuing the logging request." This happens in `ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.CallerData` and `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil`, repectively. Basically, the frameworks examine the stack trace until they are reasonably sure to have left their own codebase, then use the "next" class they encounter on the stack.
 In your case, this is the `MyLogger` class.

The easisest way to avoid the situation is to abandon the `%C` format specifier altogether. While useful in debuggíng, the stack introspections have a serious impact on performance and can not handle situations such as yours cleanly.

The `%c` format specifier inserts the name of the logger instead. If you initialize the logger corrrectly:

```
// static logger
private static final Logger STATIC_LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OtherClass.class);

// instance logger
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

`%c` yields the expected output. This also allows for advanced logging solutions such as multiple loggers per class for e.g. audit logging.

If you absolutely have to use the `%C` specifier, Logback offers an option to set the framework packages that are ignored by the caller scan:

```
// during application startup
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
lc.getFrameworkPackages().add("foo.bar.logging")
```

Note that this will effectively disable `%C` output for the entire `foo.bar.logging` package. Log4j 2 does not appear to offer a similar configuration option.

Comment: It is mandatory for me to print the FQCN of the calling class.

Comment: I've tried with the `%c` conversion character and it properly prints the calling class. The problem now is the line (`%L`) still refers to `MyLogger` instead of `OtherClass`.